# Matlab Record USB Mic

Tags: matlab, audio, signal-processing

```
input = dsp.AudioRecorder;
output = dsp.AudioPlayer;

tic;

while (toc < 5)
    stream = step(input);
    step(output, stream);
    plot(stream);
    drawnow;
end
```

I'm creating a matlab program and I need to record and playback (in real-time) audio input from a USB mic. This is what I have but it does not work. The data coming in is all 0s.

Comment: There may be some issue in your usb connection because I've tried your code and works fine, I guess.

Comment: It is an issue with my connection. The device I was using only works if it is set as the default playback and recording device.

Comment: No, this is not a connection issue -- matlab just obviously uses the device that's *default* -- because that's what default settings are for!

Comment: No it is was an issue with the connection. I contacted the company and they did say the device only worked when it was set as the default playback device.